# What might be the daily experience of someone who does not have an orientation association area?

Tags: neuroscience, philosophy-of-mind

The orientation association area gives us a sense of our body in time and space.

What would it be like without this part of the brain assuming everything else works normally?

Can the brain separate itself from the totality of everything? Can the person maneuver in the environment? Can the person know "he/she" exists without this tactile sense of separation and ability to identify? Can the person understand "life/death" without this separation?

Comment: i think it's difficult to imagine but i can venture a guess that as the person cannot conceptualize a sense of a separate entity, the person won't be able to comprehend any idea that stems from this division. any ideas of life, gender, etc that we take for granted might seem at odd's with one's daily experience. i wonder if the body would still retain it's reflex actions and react to "threats" instinctively. i would reckon these would be absent too however resulting in a distinct evolutionary disadvantage, but most likely a painless end to a life that knows no ends!